# Declaration vs definition: is GCC wrong?

Tags: c, gcc

According to ISO9899:2017 § 6.7-5:

> A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of
> identifiers. A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that
> identifier that: — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for
> that object;

I guess it’s the exact same with all versions of the C standard.

When I try to compile the following code with GCC:

```
int main(void)
{   extern int myVariable; // Declaration of myVariable.
    int myVariable; // Definition of myVariable.
    int myVariable; // Definition of myVariable.
}
```

I get the following error:

> error: **redeclaration** of 'myVariable' with no linkage

Unless I’m mistaken, the error isn't rather a redefinition?

Comment: The quote basically says that a definition is also a declaration. So you have in fact *three* declarations of the variable. :)

Comment: It's true. So there is no way in C language to declare a variable without defining it?

Comment: No, there is no way to define without declaring.

Comment: Sorry to insist but "extern int myVariable" isn't a declaration without a definition of that variable? Unless I’m mistaken, this instruction does not reserve any storage for myVariable.

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood you. You meant that it is not possible to define without declaring but not to declare without defining?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Every definition is a declaration, but not every declaration is a definition. So there is no way to have a definition which won't act as a declaration.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have this:

```
extern int myVariable;
```

The `extern` keyword makes this a *declaration* for a variable with *external linkage*.  Any such declaration will always refer to the same object.

Then you have:

```
int myVariable;
```

This identifier has *block scope* (i.e. is defined inside of a function) and therefore has *no linkage*.  Because it has no linkage, such a declaration is also a definition.

This is also an error (although you didn't show it) because you have conflicting declarations in the same scope for the same identifier, one with external linkage and one with no linkage.

Then in the same scope you have:

```
int myVariable;
```

This is an error because you have two objects with the same name and no linkage in the same scope, and therefore multiple definitions.

Section 6.2.2p2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describes linkages in more detail:

> In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an
> entire program, each declaration of a particular identifier with
> *external linkage* denotes the same object or function. Within one
> translation unit, each declaration of an identifier with *internal
> linkage* denotes the same object or function. Each declaration of an
> identifier with *no linkage* denotes a unique entity.

Comment: My only purpose of doing this was to try to dissociate definition from declaration for learning purposes. But apparently this dissociation is not possible in C language.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Actually you're right.  It's an error due to conflicting declarations.  Updated.